# trouble with Math.random()

Tags: javascript

Is there a possibility that:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
```

can come out as 7? More specifically, can:

```
Math.random()
```

come out as 1?

Comment: The documentation says no.  "...returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random.

Comment: There is an edge case, due to the limited precision of floating-point values. If `Math.random()` returns `0.9999999999999999`, then `0.9999999999999999 * 8 + 1` gives `9` (but `0.9999999999999999 * 6 + 1` still gives `6.999999999999999`). Try it in your console. I have to say I have ever seen that happen "in the wild", though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, so the calculation with *primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value* makes the problem, not the `Math.random()` itselft.

Comment: @Nina, absolutely, I was only addressing the first part of the question. I tried to compute the odds for `random()` to return `0.9999999999999999` but now my head hurts and it still probably won't ever happen in our lifespan :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)

So no, it cannot return 1.

Use one of these formulas to get what you want:

```
// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
//Example: get a random number >= 1 and < 7
Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1)) + 1; //Which is your example

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (included)
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
//Example: get a random number >= 1 and <= 7
Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, according to [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> ```
> // Returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
> function getRandom() {
>     return Math.random();
> }
> ```

or right out of the standard [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14):

> **15.8.2.14 random ( )**
>
> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.